# Discovering the true screen size (in pixels) for Android devices which have a Software Navigation Bar

Tags: android, screen

I need to be able to know the exact size of the screen excluding the Software Navigation Bar before hand. I'm using the andengine to create a game.
We wanted to fully support the new Nexus line (4, 7 and 10)

According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html), which many have pointed out, the size of the Software Navigation Bar should be 48dp.
Then using the information on [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/why-can-the-nexus-7-display-so-much-more-content-on-screen-than-the-galaxy-nexus) excellent stackexchange post I gathered the formula for calculating the size of the Software Navigation Bar should be: `px = dp * (ppi / 160)`

According to [the official site](http://www.google.com/nexus/7/specs/) the Nexus 7 has a 216 ppi screen.
The Software Navigation Bar should then be: `48 * (216 / 160) = 64.8 ≈ 64px`
We have a Nexus 7 tablet and the Software Navigation Bar is 75px.

This means that either the ppi value is `(75 * 160) / 48 = 250`
or
the dp size is in fact `(75 / 216) * 160 = 55.555... ≈ 55dp`

So which is it?

Furthermore the 4.2 Android SDK comes with some premade AVDs. Included among them is the Nexus 7. There the size of the Software Navigation Bar is reported to be 64px...

I'm not asking for the sizes of these devices, I can just google (or search stackexchange) for those numbers. Is it not possible to be sure of a device's screen size without purchasing that device?

**[edit]**
I thought I should add that I'm getting the screen size with the following method:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics screenSize = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(screenSize);
CAMERA_WIDTH = screenSize.widthPixels;
CAMERA_HEIGHT = screenSize.heightPixels;
```

Comment: you meant the pixel size not the physical size, did u? Could you change the title a little bit to avoid the confusion :)?

Comment: Nexus 7 has hdpi/tvdpi screen which is 1.5 times of mdpi and Nexus 4/Galaxy Nexus is xhdpi screen, so the number is 2 times. Thus the 48dp bar on N7 will be 48*1.5=72px, on N4/GN will be 48*2=96px

Comment: e.g. Galaxy Nexus has a 720x1184 px screen w/o the bar, and the full height of the screen is 1280. so the bar takes 96px. GN's screen is 360x592 dp w/o the bar. the bar is 48dp.

Comment: Except that it's not 72px. It's 75px. It's ppi doesn't fall within the hdpi range but the mdpi/tvdpi.

Comment: Then it should be 48*(213/160)=63.9≈64px according to https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8 the density of Nexus 7 should be 213 not 216. And for your question, I'm curious to know the answer as well :)

Comment: Well, I've made an screenshot of the Nexus 7 and the navigation bar is 64 pixels high, not 75, nor 72

Answer (score 3):

Better later then never. I was looking for something like this, and second link was this question, but first was
http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

For example

Nexus 4

1280 x 768 px (640 x 384 dp) / xhdpi / Normal screen
Portrait Details

Navigation bar height:  96 px (48 dp)
Title bar height:   96 px (48 dp)
Status bar height:  50 px (25 dp)
Content View:   1038 x 768 px
(519 x 384 dp)
Landscape Details

Navigation bar width:   84 px (42 dp)
Title bar height:   80 px (40 dp)
Status bar height:  50 px (25 dp)
Content View:   638 x 1196 px
(319 x 598 dp)

I believe it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Software navigation bar height is 48dp.

96px @ xhdpi **/** 
144px @ xxhdpi **/** 
I don't think you would find it @hdpi phone but it would be 72px.

---

Notification bar height seems to have 25dp (Android 4+).

38px @ hdpi **/** 
50px @ xhdpi **/** 
75px @ xxhdpi

---

It gives you:
**1134px** @ xhdpi (@1280px height) **/** **1701px** @ xxhdpi (@1920px height) **/**
of available space.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here. My problem was with the Nexus 7 which should have a navigation bar of 64px but it was reported as 75px when I checked it in code.
Also the Nexus 7 is a tvdpi device.